# Bullseye scoring game - Wrong to try to use pure JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a *logically* simple game featuring a bullseye and 8-round scoreboard.  I use a circular image map with onClick events on each area to write the appropriate scoring amounts.  Example: Middle of bullseye is 6 points, next ring out is 4, next out is 3, and so on.  I'm using **session storage** to store # of players, player names, whose turn it is, etc.

I'm fairly deep in to version 1 and have most of it working, but I'm starting to hit some issues due to the way I built it.  I've hit an issue where it's hard to work with the HTML table because the table HTML renders before all my JS fires in the  of the document.  Example of issue:  I ask for the # of players as the first step in the game.  I need to write a table row per player and I can't do that if the page has already been rendered.  Additionally, when it comes time to announce the winner, I don't have a good way to relate the player name and total player score.

So my question is... is it wrong to try to do this with pure HTML and JS?  Would jQuery (or another language) make this easier?  I don't have a ton of experience with jQuery.  Would you instead use a database to temporarily store the # of players, names, scores, etc?

Perhaps I could break off the prompt pieces of the game to a separate page(s)?  E.g. Page1 asks how many players, Page2 asks for their names, and Page3 builds up the bullseye and scoreboard?  I'd still have to solve the issue of relating player name and total score.

My code isn't in sufficient shape to show the masses, so this is more of a theoretical post.  Thanks!

[image: Before Scoring]

[image: During Scoring]

Comment: Jquery is not another language. It's an increasingly obsolete library for javascript.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I don't see why it would be considered obsolete. While cross-browser compatibility is much less of an issue now, it still allows one to accomplish more with less code in many cases.

Comment: I will add that I don't need to worry about this working on any systems other than the one I'm designing for.  I can lock down browser, screen size, viewport size, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to write a table row per player and I can't do that if the page has already been rendered.

Why not?  You can easily modify existing html after it has rendered:

```js
const add = document.getElementById("add")
const players = document.getElementById("players").querySelector('tbody');
add.addEventListener("click", () => {
   const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
   const playerName = document.createElement('td');
   const playerScore = document.createElement('td');
   const controls = document.createElement('td');
   controls.innerHTML = `
       <button class="incrementScore">+</button>
       <button class="decrementScore">-</button>
   `;
   playerScore.innerHTML = 0
   newRow.appendChild(playerName);
   newRow.appendChild(playerScore);
   newRow.appendChild(controls);
   controls.querySelector('.incrementScore').addEventListener('click', () => {
       playerScore.innerHTML = parseInt(playerScore.innerHTML) + 1;
   });
   controls.querySelector('.decrementScore').addEventListener('click', () => {
       playerScore.innerHTML = parseInt(playerScore.innerHTML) - 1;
   });
   const name = prompt('name?');
   playerName.innerHTML = name;
   players.appendChild(newRow);
});
```

```html
<table id="players" border=1>
<thead><tr><th>Player</th><th>Score</th><th></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfooter>
<tr><td colspan=3><button id="add">+ Add Player</button></td></tr>
</tfooter>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting!  I'll give this a try.  Thanks!

Comment: My table has a <thead> and <tbody>.  When I try to adapt this to my page, the new <tr> and <td>s get placed outside <tbody>.  Is there a way to make sure the nesting gets written correctly?

I have to tweak your example a bit since I'm using session storage numPlayers, which comes in from a prompt().  My for loops numPlayers times to build up the appropriate # of table rows, filling in the players' names as it goes.

Comment: See edit - you just have to make sure you add elements to the correct parent, and if it's easier you can just use `innerHTML` to write the whole block at once like I demonstrated with the control buttons

Comment: Awesome!  I was able to get that to work without much fuss.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) might be better suited for your tasks rather than using plain HTML elements. The Canvas API provides you with more granular control over displaying graphics, hence is more suited for games.

You may also look into the [WebGl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API), which allows for both 3D and 2D graphic rendering. [Unity 3D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html), for example, uses the WebGl API.

Answer (score -1):

You can do whatever you want there - our group simply wanted a request to go to our backend server to log fulfillment or mistakes as you can [see](https://erasurvey.org/mypricerite-experience/). (We replace #loginUrl# with an surroundings-unique value. I can not use my environment record for this, so that is executed via our pipeline)